# Docker resolves maven artifacts only from local repository?

Tags: docker, maven

I have a working `java` `spring-boot` application that fetches a dependency from a `gitlab` repository.

That works fine on a local `mvn package` command. But as soon as I execute the mvn command inside a local `docker` container, maven tries to resolve the **spring** artifacts also from my gitlab repository. Why?

`Dockerfile`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM maven:3.8.4-eclipse-temurin-11 as dependencies
COPY pom.xml .
COPY settings.xml .
RUN mvn --debug -U -B package -s settings.xml
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    
     <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://git.example.com/api/v4/projects/295/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    
    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Result:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.6 from [gitlab-maven (https://git.example.com/api/v4/projects/295/packages/maven, default, releases+snapshots), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://git.example.com/api/v4/projects/295/packages/maven
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://git.example.com/api/v4/projects/295/packages/maven
[INFO] Downloading from gitlab-maven: https://git.example.com/api/v4/projects/295/packages/maven/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.6.6/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.6.6.pom
```

`settings.xml`:

```
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <configuration>
                <httpHeaders>
                    <property>
                        <name>Private-Token</name>
                        <value>xxx</value>
                    </property>
                </httpHeaders>
            </configuration>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

Comment: From where else should it resolve - it's the only known repository inside your container?

Comment: Every maven project inherits from the default central maven repository. This is normally present, regardless how many custom repositories are added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have been any sort of caching issue. I removed docker configs, restarted the machine, now it works.

Answer (score -1):

Your query is why is resolve to your git repo right?

You are building the pom with your repo path, so it resolve to your repo

`````
 <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://git.example.com/api/v4/projects/295/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

````
`````